# Why macOS dictation commands (select sentence, etc.) doesn't work with Microsoft Office for Mac?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, voice-dictation, onenote

Dictation and dictation commands work fine for all other applications. However, when I try to use them in Microsoft Word or OneNote the literal text like *select sentence* is typed out, rather than the command being run.

What is the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: What dictation software are you using and what version of macOS are you running?

Comment: What version of word?  It may just not yet support everything yet...

Comment: I am using Office 2016, and macOS Sierra. The dictation is built in with Sierra.